# Am I running on an Emulator or a Device

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, emulation

Is there a way (using managed code hopefully) to find out if I am running on an Emulator or an actual physical device?

I am looking for something like this:

```
public class BarcodeScannerFactory
{
  public override BarcodeScanner GetBarcodeScanner() 
  {
    if (IsARealDevice())    <---------------------------+
       return new SymbolBarcodeScanner();               |
    else                                                |
       return new FakeBarcodeScanner();                 |
  }                                                     |
}                                                       |
                                                        |
// This is the method I need to make    ----------------+
```

(NOTE: It occurs to me that Windows Phone 7 has been lumped in with most of the tags below.  This question however, is intended for Window Mobile 6.5.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something [along these lines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2006/09/15/756755.aspx) you mean?