# Windows Mobile 6 - How to programmatically work out if you are using an emulator

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

How can I test to see if I am using an emulator or the actual windows mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole lot of searching I eventually found the answer I was looking for - [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2006/09/15/756755.aspx).
I found the link to this on another Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504431/am-i-running-on-an-emulator-or-a-device).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [GetDeviceUniqueID](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsmobile/archive/2006/01/09/510997.aspx) to see if they differ.  The emulator may return a different ID so you'd be able to distinguish between the two.

The link on GetDeviceUniqueID takes you to a blog explaining what it does and there is source code to use as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  The emulator does have a different DeviceId to the actual device that I am using.  What I really want to do is skip some device specific code when the emulator is running.  As I am working on a team I don't want to have to rely on an Id that is unique to a single emulator or device.

Comment: @Andrew:  Have you tried it on another machine?  An emulators device Id maybe the same from machine to machine.

Comment: No I haven't tried that.  I am using the device name for the time being.  All the emulators I have tried have a device name of pocket_pc and the devices don't.  I know this isn't ideal, but it gets me past my immediate issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look it up but I remember seeing an entry several years ago whereby using reflection there was a difference in version numbers on the NETCF between emulator and real hardware.  I don't remember what those values where, but "aa" was the real deal and "bb" was the emulator.  Not sure if that technique would still be valid with NET CF 3.5 but it worked on v2.

Answer (score 0):

You could P/Invoke KernelIoControl to get the device model name and see if that tells you whether it's the emulator.

```
[DllImport("coredll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool KernelIoControl([In] uint IoControlCode,
  [In] byte[] InputBuffer,
  [In] uint InputBufferSize,
  [In, Out] byte[] OutputBuffer,
  [In] uint OutputBufferSize,
  [Out] out uint BytesReturned);

public const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 0x7A;
public const int SPI_GETOEMINFO = 258;
public const Int32 FILE_DEVICE_HAL = 0x00000101;
public const Int32 FILE_ANY_ACCESS = 0x0;
public const Int32 METHOD_BUFFERED = 0x0;

private static uint CTL_CODE(uint DeviceType, uint Function, uint Method, 
 uint Access)
{
  return ((DeviceType << 16) | (Access << 14) | (Function << 2) | Method);
}

public static uint IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICE_INFO = CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_HAL, 1,
            METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);

public static string GetDeviceModelName()
{
  byte[] inputBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(SPI_GETOEMINFO);
  byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[256];
  uint bytesReturned = 0;

  // call KernelIoControl with IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICE_INFO parameter
  bool retVal = false;
  try
  {
    retVal = KernelIoControl(IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICE_INFO,
               inputBuffer, (uint)inputBuffer.Length, outputBuffer,
               (uint)outputBuffer.Length, out bytesReturned);
  }
  catch
  {
  }

  // if not succeeded, then try the last step again, now with increased buffer size
  if (!retVal)
  {
    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

    // if the buffer size is incorrect, adjust it and call function again.
    if (error == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
      int buffSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(outputBuffer, 0);
      outputBuffer = new byte[buffSize];
      BitConverter.GetBytes(buffSize).CopyTo(outputBuffer, 0);

      retVal = KernelIoControl(IOCTL_HAL_GET_DEVICE_INFO,
                 inputBuffer, (uint)inputBuffer.Length, outputBuffer,
                 (uint)outputBuffer.Length, out bytesReturned);
    }
  }

  // extract the model name
  string modelNameStr = null;
  if (retVal)
  {
    modelNameStr = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(outputBuffer, 0, 
                     outputBuffer.Length).Replace("\0","");
  }

  return modelNameStr;
}
```